# Django - Upload a file to a network shared storage

Tags: django, network-storage

I'm using Django v1.7 and my app uploads files to a local storage. The thing is, I have a load balancer and 2 front end machines server the django app.
Therefore I need to run a task periodically to sync the content of both local storages from the front end servers.... Is there any way to upload to a remote location, like a network storage? (e.g. may I uploaded it to remote IP or something?)

I'm sorry, but I haven't found a solution for this yet :(

Cheers,

Comment: What about using a network storage which both servers have access to, you could simply mount it into your existing filesystem and tell django the path for its media storage?

You can also check out https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which provide django file storages to store your data directly on a cloud provider or on a remote ftp.

Comment: @blacklwhite shall I user something like this as media URL?

MEDIA_URL = '\\AMPTNPRATA\__media__\'

Comment: That should work

Comment: nop... MEDIA_URL does not accept backslash :\

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash? "\\\\AMPTNPRATA__media__\\"

Comment: yeah mate, but it doesn't even accept it since it requires a slash in the end

Comment: …and if you mount the network location as a drive? `net use X: \\AMPTNPRATA__media__\ /persistent:yes /user:admin password`, and use `X:/` as your media url?

Comment: I think that's it my friend! I use that approach to upload shared resources, but I thought that with the /media/ files there was a simpler approach. I'll try that and then get back to you. Thanks for everything.